# 403 error when trying to create a folder with Sharepoint's REST-API

Tags: python, sharepoint

So, I am trying to create a new folder in my sharepoint using POST and the Office365-REST-Python-Client.
Somehow I always get a 403 error: `403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://<my tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/folders')`

I followed the steps in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs to get proper auth-tokens but somehow I am missing some permissions because all get-requests are working fine.

The `Permission-Request-XML` was:

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Would be great if someone could tell me which are missing and how I can get these.

Ah, before I forget my code is:

```py
url = 'https://<my tenant>.sharepoint.com'#/sites/wevest_capital/'
context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)


ctx = ClientContext(url, context_auth)

folderURL = '/sites/<my Site>/Shared Documents/Test'

source_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folderURL)
target_folder = ctx.web.folders.add(folderURL).execute_query()
```

Edit: Found a "workaround": I am using a newer library with access to the new MS-Graph authentication-endpoints

Comment: Which newer library do you use? Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyMazur Ouh completely forgot this post. Built my own wrapper exactly fitting to my needs because every other library wasn't nearly close to fitting. I can put it on github and share with you if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

I get tired of trying to solve this. UserCredential worked for me but i still prefering the access token way

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
site_url = 'https://[TENANT].sharepoint.com/sites/[site]/'
        
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("email", "pass"))
```